# How to convert VARCHAR columns to DECIMAL without rounding in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, decimal, rounding

In my SQL class, I'm working with a table that is all `VARCHAR`. I'm trying to convert each column to a more correct data type.

For example. I have a column called `Item_Cost` that has a value like:

```
1.25000000000000000000
```

I tried to run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> 
    ALTER COLUMN Item_Cost DECIMAL
```

This query does run successfully, but it turns it into 1 instead of 1.25.

How do I prevent the rounding?

Comment: I'd also point out that in this specific scenario, if it's truly an item_cost column, you could also make the column a `money` data type, and it would take care of the trailing zeroes and do no rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql) for the data type `decimal`. The type is defined by optional parameters `p (precision)` and `s (scale)`. The latter determines the numbers to the right of the decimal point.

Extract from the documentation (I highlighted the important bit in bold):

> s (scale)
>
> The number of decimal digits that are stored to the right of
> the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the
> maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must
> be a value from 0 through p, and can only be specified if precision is
> specified. **The default scale is 0** and so 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage
> sizes vary, based on the precision.

Defining a suitable precision and scale fixes your issue.

**Sample data**

```
create table MyData
(
  Item_Cost nvarchar(100)
);

insert into MyData (Item_Cost) values ('1.25000000000000000000');
```

**Solution**

```
ALTER TABLE MyData Alter Column Item_Cost DECIMAL(10, 3);
```

**Result**

```
Item_Cost
---------
1.250
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=539b32f2ea7f4377abfe0997de01a6ff)