# SQL convert nvarchar into decimal dynamic rows

Tags: sql, dynamic, type-conversion, decimal, nvarchar

I am not so familiar with using convert in SQL so thats why i am stuck with the following situation:

The column has a nvarchar(max) and i would like to convert it into decimal (18,2). But there are some rows that consist a "full" amount (see red box). For all values with the full amount i would like to have it as 1222,00

[image]

When creating a SQL view I got this error:
**Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.**

[image]
How can i still convert this column into decimal?

Many thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Here is few examples that where already answered: [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056035/alter-mysql-table-varchar-fields-to-decimal-fields), [SQL-Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775108/how-to-convert-varchar-columns-to-decimal-without-rounding-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi @Aarlaneth unfortunatly, this suggestion doesnt work for me.

Comment: I got a error : Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric when creating the follow SQL View. I think because some of the records of the column have already a decimal values and two records have a full amount such as 1222 and 1247. Any suggestions @Aarlaneth

CREATE VIEW viewB

AS

SELECT

[Category]         as Year,
CONVERT(decimal(18,2),[Zorg en welzijn(smal)])  as [Zorg en welzijn(smal)]
FROM dbo.[tableA]

GO

Comment: Tag your RDBMS so we can actually help you..

Comment: And [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Edit your question so your data is posted as text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your pictures it *seems* to me like you are using SQL-Server. If so your problem is having `,` as decimal point instead of `.` It has nothing to do with having whole and decimal numbers in your data.

So you should replace it before converting data.

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,2), REPLACE(ColumnName,',','.')) FROM TableName
```

[DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8xfqC4nC)